# Is it possible to ssh into another system from one I'm ssh'ed into using paramiko?

Tags: python, ssh, paramiko

I'm writing a script that will ssh into a raspberry pi, and then from the raspberry pi, will ssh into another system to verify that it can connect.

From the windows terminal, I can do this just fine. I can log into my pi with `ssh pi@raspberry`, and then while logged in, I can run `ssh [SYSNAME]` (I have a config set for this system in my ~/.ssh/config file on my pi) and log into the other system.

I'm using paramiko with python 3.9.7, and I can log into the pi just fine, but then when I try to ssh into the [SYSNAME], it gives me `[USER]@[IP]: Permission denied (publickey)`. I did have to add a special ssh key to access this other system on the pi using `ssh-add ~/.ssh/other_key`, but I'm not experienced enough to know if this key isn't being used whiled using paramiko.

[This is my code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xRpAj.png)

Thanks in advance!

EDIT:
I found my issue. While I did add the special_key, it was not being used for some reason. Once I manually added the key using `ssh -i ~/.ssh/special_key [USER]@[IP] -p 22`, it worked. Now my issue is getting that working without manually specifying the key, but I'm sure I can figure that out. Thanks all!

Comment: Not familiar with Paramiko but the ordinary ssh calls this approach "jump host" - `ssh -J pi@raspberry [SERVER]` does exactly what you do manually with `ssh`. Maybe there would be an option for that?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! When I switch the command to `ssh -J pi@raspberry [SERVER]`, I'm now getting `pi@raspberry: Permission denied (publickey,password).
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host`

Comment: Using `ssh -J` doesn't honor your remote `~/.ssh/config`, only your local one. You're thus expected to have everything you need to authenticate to the remote system (the final hop) on your local box, not on your first hop.

Comment: Oh, I did not know that about the config, sorry about misleading you @AlexKolstad

Comment: To be clear, that doesn't mean using it is the wrong thing. It's better to keep those credentials tightly held; hopefully the system you're starting from is better secured than your Raspberry Pi (though if it's Windows, maybe that's not a safe hope).

Comment: I think I'm getting closer, I get the same publickey error when I try to ssh from my desktop to the other system, so I'm guessing I need to add the same special ssh key to my desktop as well.